# Docker DB connection refused error while attaching DB to web container

Tags: mysql, docker, laravel-5, docker-compose

I am new to docker and trying to dockerize my laravel app (version 5.1)

Following is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
    ports:
      - "3307:3306/tcp"
    volumes:
      - test_db:/var/lib/test_db/data
  web:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: deploy/Dockerfile
      args:
        APP_ENV: "local"
    environment:
      APP_DEBUG: "true"   
      DB_HOST: "db"
      DB_DATABASE: "test"
      DB_USERNAME: "root"
      DB_PASSWORD: "root"      
    ports:
      - "443:8000/tcp"
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/html
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db     
    restart: on-failure:10
    container_name: test_web 
volumes:
  test_db:
```

When I execute `docker-compose up` command, I get the following error

```
[PDOException]                             
test_web |   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

As I have set 10 retries so it ultimately connects and migrations are executed but I have the following issues:

- Why the connection do not get established instantly or within few retries?
- I am using named volumes but the data dont seem to get persistent. Everytime when i run `docker-compose up`, migrations are executed and the data gets overwritten

Please let me know what are the possible issue behind the above two issues

Comment: The database takes a minute or so to be ready.  You can see this in `docker-compose logs` output.  Until it's ready your connections will fail.

Comment: @DavidMaze as long as the web service has the depends_on flag with the database no connection should be tried before the connection is possible? To your second point, try to mount the data locally to take a look if the path inside the container is correct here https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql it is described, the path inside is /var/lib/mysql

Comment: `depends_on:` only affects the order Docker Compose starts the container.  So it will always start starting MySQL before it starts starting the application, but MySQL takes a minute or so to "finish starting" and there's no way for Docker to realize that.

Comment: @DavidMaze the path of volume cant be any other than `/var/lib/mysql`?

Answer (score 0):

A database will be always slow to start .

`depends_on:`  is a way to affects the sequence of start .

One solution is to modify the `CMD` in your dockerfile , to wait until a condition .

i use `nc` ( aka netcat ) to test if the port 3306 of `db`  is ready .

replace `sleep 7200` by your startup command

```
CMD ["/bin/sh","-c", \
 "( while ( ! nc -z db 3306 >/dev/null 2>&1 ) ; do \
       date ; sleep 4 ; \
    done ;  \
    sleep 7200 ;  ) " ]
```

Comment: isnt  `restart: on-failure:10` doing the same thing? retrying db connection?

Comment: `restart` restart the container , my solution  is to wait until a condition  , and do the job .